# How do I have my method wait for all threads to finish?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a method that is firing off threads to do some work. There will be 2 threads running asynchronously for a period of time, and when their callback method get's called, the callback fires off another thread until all the work has been finished. How do I make my method wait for all these threads to finish and be fired off?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Waiting for all threads to complete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263116/c-waiting-for-all-threads-to-complete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interlocked.Increment an initially zeroed counter just before starting any thread.  Interlocked.Decrement a counter in every thread just before exit/loopback.  If any thread decrements the counter to zero, Set() an AutoResetEvent.  WaitOne() on the AutoResetEvent.

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: Having noted the other posts, I should maybee add - my solution works no matter how many threads are started - sometimes this is not known at compile time. Also, solutions using Join() should work fine providing the threads actually exit - if they loop around and wait on something to do more work later, Join() will not work. Another point - WaitHandle.WaitAll can only handle (!), 64 handles - a  restriction on the WaitForMultipleObjects() API used internally, (propably nitpicking by now - I should shut up :).

Answer (score 6):

If this is .Net 4.0, you can use a [`CountdownEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx)

```
const int threads = 10;
using( CountdownEvent evt = new CountdownEvent(threads) )
{
    for( int x = 0; x < threads; ++x )
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
            {
                // Do work here
                ((CountdownEvent)state).Signal();
            }, evt);
    }

    evt.Wait();
}
Console.WriteLine("Everyone finished!");
```

This has the advantage of working when `Thread.Join` isn't an option (e.g. if you're using the thread pool), and scaling better than using wait handles (because `WaitHandle.WaitAll` has a maximum of 64 handles, and you also don't need to allocate as many objects).

Note that if you're using .Net 4 you can also use the Task Parallel Library which makes this kind of thing easier.

**Update:**

Since you said this isn't .Net 4.0, here's a simple version of the `CountdownEvent` that can be used in .Net 3.5. I originally wrote it because I needed a CountdownEvent I could use in Mono at a time that Mono didn't support .Net 4 yet. It's not as flexible as the real one but it does what you need:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a synchronization primitive that is signaled when its count reaches zero.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// <para>
///   This class is similar to but less versatile than .Net 4's built-in CountdownEvent.
/// </para>
/// </remarks>
public sealed class CountdownEvent : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _reachedZeroEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private volatile int _count;
    private volatile bool _disposed;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CountdownEvent"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="initialCount">The initial count.</param>
    public CountdownEvent(int initialCount)
    {
        _count = initialCount;
    }

    // Disable volatile not treated as volatile warning.
#pragma warning disable 420

    /// <summary>
    /// Signals the event by decrementing the count by one.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns><see langword="true" /> if the count reached zero and the event was signalled; otherwise, <see langword="false"/>.</returns>
    public bool Signal()
    {
        CheckDisposed();

        // This is not meant to prevent _count from dropping below zero (that can still happen due to race conditions),
        // it's just a simple way to prevent the function from doing unnecessary work if the count has already reached zero.
        if( _count <= 0 )
            return true;

        if( Interlocked.Decrement(ref _count) <= 0 )
        {
            _reachedZeroEvent.Set();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

#pragma warning restore 420

    /// <summary>
    /// Blocks the calling thread until the <see cref="CountdownEvent"/> is set.
    /// </summary>
    public void Wait()
    {
        CheckDisposed();
        _reachedZeroEvent.WaitOne();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Blocks the calling thread until the <see cref="CountdownEvent"/> is set, using a <see cref="TimeSpan"/> to measure the timeout.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="timeout">The timeout to wait, or a <see cref="TimeSpan"/> representing -1 milliseconds to wait indefinitely.</param>
    /// <returns><see langword="true"/> if the <see cref="CountdownEvent"/> was set; otherwise, <see langword="false"/>.</returns>
    public bool Wait(TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        CheckDisposed();
        return _reachedZeroEvent.WaitOne(timeout, false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Blocks the calling thread until the <see cref="CountdownEvent"/> is set, using a 32-bit signed integer to measure the timeout.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="millisecondsTimeout">The timeout to wait, or <see cref="Timeout.Infinite"/> (-1) to wait indefinitely.</param>
    /// <returns><see langword="true"/> if the <see cref="CountdownEvent"/> was set; otherwise, <see langword="false"/>.</returns>
    public bool Wait(int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        CheckDisposed();
        return _reachedZeroEvent.WaitOne(millisecondsTimeout, false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if( !_disposed )
        {
            if( disposing )
                ((IDisposable)_reachedZeroEvent).Dispose();
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }

    private void CheckDisposed()
    {
        if( _disposed )
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(typeof(CountdownEvent).FullName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just in addition, CountdownEvent implementation based on Monitor class from [Joe Albahari](http://stackoverflow.com/users/46223/joe-albahari) - http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Writing_a_CountdownEvent

Answer (score 5):

Simple call `Join` on all the threads. So if you've just got two thread variables:

```
thread1.Join();
thread2.Join();
```

Or if you've got a collection:

```
foreach (Thread thread in threads)
{
    thread.Join();
}
```

It doesn't matter what order the threads finish in; the code will only continue after all the threads have completed.

If you've got new threads being created all the time, however, this may not help much... you *may* need to have some collection (e.g. a queue) which is only accessed within a lock, and get each thread-spawning activity to add the new thread to a queue... then iterate (carefully!) until the queue is empty:

```
while (true)
{
    Thread nextThread;
    lock (collectionLock)
    {
        if (queue.Count == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        nextThread = queue.Dequeue();
    }
    nextThread.Join();
}
```

Ideally though, try using the Task Parallel Library if you're on .NET 4 - it makes a lot of this stuff easier :)

Comment: I'm using the thread pool so how would I do Thread.join if I'm just queueing user work items? Also I can't use TPL because I'm on 3.5 and cannot get 4 :/

Comment: @Joey: Okay, if you're using the thread pool that makes life harder. Your question says you're "firing off threads" which isn't quite the same thing... it's always worth being careful when writing questions :)

Comment: Well I can easily change it to utilize threads which I think I will.

Comment: @Joey Gfd: I updated my answer with a custom implementation of the `CountdownEvent` that I wrote for a personal project a while back that you'll be able to use in .Net 3.5. You can use that with the `ThreadPool` easily.

Answer (score 1):

Use WaitHandles, each thread should have a WaitHandle, such as ManualResetEvent and when finished call Set() on the event.

The main method should use [WaitHandle.WaitAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.waitall.aspx) passing in the handles for each thread.

```
        IList<WaitHandle> waitHandles = new List<WaitHandle>();
        var newThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart((handle) =>
        {
            // thread stuff goes here

            ((ManualResetEvent)handle).Set();
        }));
        var manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        waitHandles.Add(manualResetEvent);
        newThread.Start(manualResetEvent);

        // create other threads similarly

        // wait for all threads to complete - specify a timeout to prevent a deadlock if a thread fails to set the event
        WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles.ToArray());
```

Comment: `WaitAll` also has a 64 handle limit so it is not very scalable.

Answer (score 0):

In simplest situation you can use Join

```
    Threading.Thread myThread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Worker1));
    Threading.Thread myThread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Worker2));
    myThread1.Start();
    myThread2.Start();
    myThread1.Join();
    myThread2.Join();
```